# Correct way to clear preferences and make it use values from XML file?

Tags: android, preferences

So I was doing some development and changed the key names (android:key) of some preferences I have in my settings.xml file. During some testing I realized that the old settings (old keys and values) were still there, even though my new settings.xml file didn't have them anymore.

I had been doing this when my app started:

```
 PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, false);
```

Which isn't removing the old settings that are no longer in my settings file.

Then tried this:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
```

And finally this:

```
  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().clear();
  PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.settings, true);
```

But the old keys/values are still there. Ok, so now I just restarted the emulator with "Clear user data" checked, so that I'm sure will do the trick. But what is the correct way to do this other than that?

What is the correct way to clear the old settings out?

Comment: you were calling commit() on the editor after making those changes right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After your final example, you have to do a commit.
I would recommend breaking the steps out to make it easier to read.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Using the same Editor instance is critical to make sure you're commiting the right content. It's not necessary when it's a single change, but always good practice. The key point here, though, is **editor.commit();**

Comment: @Aleadam I'm not sure I follow... is there something incorrect about my code?

Comment: no, actually the first upvote was mine. I just wanted to add a little to your answer, stating that it was a good practice to separate it, but not really necessary for this example. What was missing from the question (and correctly present in your answer) was the `commit()` part, and thus I marked it in bold.

Comment: @Aleadam Ah, got it. Thought I might have a bunch of code to fix! :)

Comment: It worked when i replaced your first line with this   SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Otherwise, i was getting compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

In short and full:

```
  private void prefSetDefaults()
  {
    SharedPreferences.Editor
        editor ;
        editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, true); //true = xml default
  }
```

(where `preferences.xml` contains preferences, each with defined `android:defaultValue`).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Editor.remove(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#remove%28java.lang.String%29) on the old values you want to remove?

Comment: 1) It's **remove**, not **remote** and 2) most importantly, remove is not a static method. See Nick Campion's answer for a correct way to refer to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that sometimes some things just don't update correctly onto the emulator/phone.
Go to settings on your phone/emulator, remove the app.  Re-install the app.